# Locating element with id having underscore

Tags: java, regex, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

First thing, am new to selenium, and am trying my hands on automation.
I have a problem where the 'XPATH' changes dynamically. Only the first part of the xpath and the last part are constant, but the problem is both the first and last parts have 'underscores' in them, and my expression is not able to identify it.

My Xpath:

```
ctl00_m_g_1140dfe4_4238_447b_b837_a62e12617b03_ctl00_rptLeftNav_ctl00_rptLeftNavSubCat_ctl00_lnkNavSubCat
```

I have tried using the below webdriver code:

```
dr.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id[contains(., '_ctl00_rptLeftNavSubCat_ctl00_lnkNavSubCat')]]")).click;
```

But, i get the error message saying as below.

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element

I have read somewhere that 'underscores' cannot be used in regex, is it true? Can someone please provide a solution here? Would be very grateful.

Comment: Could you provide an actual HTML example? Without it, any answer will be guess work. Since the problem doesn't seem to be related to underscores.

Answer (score 2):

These numbers inside the `id` attribute look like dynamically generated. Instead, locate the element checking for `rptLeftNav`, `rptLeftNavSubCat` and `lnkNavSubCat`:

```
//input[contains(@id, 'rptLeftNav') and contains(@id, 'rptLeftNavSubCat') and contains(@id, 'lnkNavSubCat')]
```

You are also confusing XPath and Regular expressions. Here we are talking about only the selenium webdriver and writing an XPath expression to locate an element.

You may also need to *wait for the element to become present*:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'rptLeftNav') and contains(@id, 'rptLeftNavSubCat') and contains(@id, 'lnkNavSubCat')]")));
```

Comment: @SamuelSudhir do you see any iframe elements on the page?

Comment: Thanks @alexce, but unfortunately am facing the same error, maybe becuase i have elements with similar xpath as mentioned above. For eg., let me give you two xpaths as below.  XPATH 1 : ctl00_m_g_1140dfe4_4238_447b_b837_a62e12617b03_ctl00_rptLeftNav_ctl00_rptLeftNavSubCat_ctl00_lnkNavSubCat

Comment: @Alexce : I do not see any iframe elements as such.

Comment: @SamuelSudhir I've added some more information to the answer, check it out.

Comment: @Alexce : Thanks for the quick response, let me try it out rigth now.

Comment: @Alexce : Unfortunately 'timeout' error appears saying the "Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //input[contains(@id, 'rptLeftNav') and contains(@id, 'rptLeftNavSubCat') and contains(@id, 'lnkNavSubCat')]"

Comment: @SamuelSudhir can you share a link to the web-site so I can test it? Thanks.

Comment: I would be more than happy to but am working on a client website which am not allowed to share, apologies :( ! But ive tried 'Starts-With', 'Ends-With', nothing works, read somewhere that 'underscore' is not recognizable by regex ? is it true ?

Answer (score 1):

My friend has found a solution for this while searching online. This can be resolved using 'cssselector'.

```
dr.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[id^='ctl00'][id$='_ctl00_rptLeftNav_ctl00_lnkNavigation']")).click();
```

Quite relieved now :) !!